# Kotlin gives wrong result when multipliyng

Tags: kotlin, floating-point

I want to multiply `281.65` by `100` and get `28165`, I execute:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("${281.65 * 100}")
}
```

but I get `28164.999999999996`
Whats the problem here and how do I get `28165` as a result?
Is there a good Kotlin way to work with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 8):

Yep, it's [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) math issue.

`kotlin.math` package has `roundToLong` extension function which helps in this case.

```
(281.65 * 100).roundToLong()
```